# Getting color with hex numbers using WebService on android

Tags: android, web, service, colors, hex

I want to write a webservice on android. I have hexadecimal color codes(#a445a1). What i wanna do is sending these codes to website and to get their images to show on the screen. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send your hex color code as a string *"#a445a1"* and in your server you can convert from string to hex color using this function in this [Tuto](http://mrkmg.com/php-function-to-generate-a-color-from-a-text-string/)